# Python - Image to text enclosed in pentagon shape pytesseract

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, opencv, python-tesseract

I am trying to ready Energy Efficiency Rating from EPC certificate using python. Usually EPC certificate comes in PDF format. I have converted PDF into image already and using pytesseract to get text from image. However I am not getting expected results.

Sample Image:
[image]

Expected output:
Current rating : 79, Potential rating : 79

What I have tried so far:

```
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image

pages = convert_from_path(r'my_file.pdf', 500)
img =pages[0].save(r'F:\Freelancer\EPC rating\fwdepcs\out.jpg', 'JPEG')
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(r'F:\Freelancer\EPC rating\fwdepcs\out.jpg'))
```

However text does not capture 79.

I also tried cv2 pattern matching and shape detection, but those not worked for other reasons.

Answer (score 2):

You say that you have convert this pdf to image file.

Use PIL(.crop()) or opencv to crop picture.And crop it like this:

[image]

And use PIL `Image.convert("1")`,maybe tesseract can catch this number.
If not,I think you can use **jTessBoxEditor** to train tesseract.

Comment: how to detect where to crop programmatic way? I am trying to automate this task.

Comment: @BhaveshGhodasara Is every picture like this ???If so,then I think you can just get those pixel position manually.

Comment: @BhaveshGhodasara I mean that,You can get the one of picture pixels' position manually.Then loop all of those pictures to capture ``Current rating ``and ``Potential rating``.

Comment: convert('1') not worked either. do you know how to train using jTessBoxEditor. any document link will help.

Comment: @BhaveshGhodasara I have some chinese example for how to use jTessBoxEditor.I can give you the blog if you don't care it is chinese.

Comment: @BhaveshGhodasara Here is the [blog page](https://blog.csdn.net/qq_40147863/article/details/82290015)

Comment: @BhaveshGhodasara BTW,If you think it is inconvenient,you can use some commercial OCR api to detect those number,It may be more effective